# Как зарезервировать место в блоке HTML под скроллбар

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть прелоадер. до того как страница загружена он появляется, при этом весь html ещё не загружен, по этому как только браузер загружает весь контент, в этот момент появляется скроллбар, в итоге выходит неприятный эффект дёргания блока, ибо прелоадер двигается влево на всю ширину скроллбара.

Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Jquery

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $('.preloader').fadeOut( 300 );
    setTimeout(function () {$('.preloader').remove()}, 300);
});
```

html

```html
<div class="preloader">
    <h1 class="title">Имя проджекта</h1>
    <ul id="loader">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #FE3B30;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000000000;
}

.preloader .title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 50px;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}

#loader {
    padding: 0;
    width: 170px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
}

@keyframes loadbars{
    0%{
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
    50%{
        height: 250px;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    100%{
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 125px;
    }
}

#loader li {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

#loader li:first-child{
    -webkit-animation:loadbars .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1) infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation:loadbars .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1) infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation:loadbars .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1) infinite 0s;
    -o-animation:loadbars .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1) infinite 0s;
    animation:loadbars .6s cubic-bezier(.645,.045,.355,1) infinite 0s
}

#loader li:nth-child(2){
    -webkit-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.2s;
    -moz-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.2s;
    -ms-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.2s;
    -o-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.2s;
    animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.2s
}

#loader li:nth-child(3){
    -webkit-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.4s;
    -moz-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.4s;
    -ms-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.4s;
    -o-animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.4s;
    animation:loadbars .6s ease-in-out infinite -.4s
}

.loaded_hiding .preloader {
    transition: 0.3s opacity;
    opacity: 0;
}

.loaded .preloader {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Самый простой способ: Выставить для body `overflow: hidden;`, после загрузки страницы, вместе с "отключением" прелоадера выставлять другое значение `overflow`.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513, прелоадер скрывается плавно, а значит он всё равно дёрнется, но уже после загрузки

Comment: @DmitryDevelop А можете показать пример? Желательно не весь код, а только необходимую часть, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему. Вариантов решения много в Вашем случае. Понять просто надо, что будет наиболее удобным.

Comment: @Denis640Kb А что именно надо? js? html? css? или скрины

Comment: @DmitryDevelop Желательно минимальный воспроизводимый пример. К примеру, часть html, которая подгружается, и `css` с `js` с частью от прелоадера.

Comment: @Denis640Kb изменил, добавил скриншоты

Comment: @DmitryDevelop Добавьте, пожалуйста, кодом, так принято тут. К сожалению, переписывать это никто не будет.

Comment: @Denis640Kb добавил

Comment: @DmitryDevelop Пока не наблюдаю дёргание блока. Вы пробовали запустить тот код, что Вы добавили? Можете на нём показать пример ошибки?

Comment: @Denis640Kb появляется при низком соединении, при нормальной скорости он грузится настолько быстро что даже не заметно изменение